# I am trying create a new list of users from a list of users who have not created an additional object with a certain property using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Really sorry for the wording of this question.

There is a scenario I am trying to address using LINQ, but I seem unable to figure it out.

I am trying to create a list of users from a different list where an additional user object with a specific property value is not present.

For example, 
I have a list of orders and each order has an authorized property.

```
 IList<Order> orderlist = new List<Order>() { 
 new Order () { Name = "James", UserIDFK = "1", Authorized = false},
 new Order () { Name = "James", UserIDFK = "1", Authorized = true},
 new Order () { Name = "Ryan", UserIDFK = "2", Authorized = false},
 new Order () { Name = "Pete", UserIDFK = "3", Authorized =  false},
 new Order () { Name = "Pete", UserIDFK = "3", Authorized =  false},
```

I am trying to create a list of ID’s from the Order List of users who do not have an additional object with the Authorized property set to “true”.

For example, I would not want to add James to this list because an Authorized order is present in the list.

I would however, like to add Ryan and Pete to the list because, no object with their Foreign key is present that has been Authorized.

I’ve attempted to use:

```
 notauthorised = orderlist.Where(y => ! orderlist.All(z => z.Authorised == 
 false)).ToList();
```

Which I understand is a really bad attempt.
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks so much for the help,
I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `UserIDFK` (or by `Name`) and then select only that groups where all `Authorized` is false

```
IList<Order> orderlist = new List<Order>() {
    new Order () { Name = "James", UserIDFK = "1", Authorized = false},
        new Order () { Name = "James", UserIDFK = "1", Authorized = true},
        new Order () { Name = "Ryan", UserIDFK = "2", Authorized = false},
        new Order () { Name = "Pete", UserIDFK = "3", Authorized =  false},
        new Order () { Name = "Pete", UserIDFK = "3", Authorized =  false},
        };

var result = orderlist
    .GroupBy(o => o.UserIDFK)
    .Where(g => g.All(x => !x.Authorized)) // will exclude James
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create a list of users ... where an additional user object with a specific property value is not present.

From your description, I gather that "property value is not present" means that property `Authorized` has a false value.

So I think that you want all distinct users that have no true values of property `Authorized`.

"I want a list of users", means that you want the `Name` and `UserIdFK` of each user that meet your predicate.

Although you didn't say so, I guess that a `User` is identified by `UserIdFK` and not by his name: two different users can both have the same name "John Doe".

To query your result, I make groups of Orders that have equal value for `UserIdFk`. After grouping I discard all Groups that have any true value for property `Authorized`. From the remaining groups I take the `UserIdFk` and the `Name`

```
// Make groups of Orders with same [UserIdFk, Name]
var usersWithoutAuthorization = orders.GroupBy(

    // KeySelector: make groups of Orders with same UserIdFk value
    order => order.UserIdFk,

   // ResultSelector: from the UserIdFk and all Orders with this UserIdFk
   (userIdFk, ordersWithThisUserIdFk) => new
   {
       UserId = userIdFk,
       Name = ordersWithThisUserIdFk.Select(order => order.Name).FirstorDefault(),
       HasAnyAuthorized = ordersWithThisUserIdFk
           .Select(order => order.Authorized)
           .Any(),
   })
   // keep only the users that have not any authorized
   .Where(groupResult => !groupResult.HasAnyAuthorized);
```

If you want, you can add an extra Select to get rid of `HasAnyAuthorized`. My advice would be to simply not use this property. This extra Select will only slow down your query, unless you fetch it from a different process, like a database management system.

If you GroupBy [userIdFk, Name], your ResultSelector will be easier, but it will probably be slower because it will also compare the Names which are strings, which of course is slower to compare than the integer `UserIdFk`